# Is it possible to exclude answers from search results?

Tags: support, search

Searches on Stack Exchange display results for both questions and answers. Is it possible to do a search that specifically only includes questions?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes.

Whereas 
https://meta.stackexchange.com/search?q=gold+tag returns questions and answers, 
https://meta.stackexchange.com/search?q=gold+tag+is%3Aquestion will return only questions.

So, just add `is:question` to your search.

For other Search tips see https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/searching